# What ISO/IEC describes H.264 NALUs, SPS, PPS, etc..?

Tags: h.264

What ISO standard describes in detail H.264 NAL units, SPS. PPS, etc..?

Is it ISO/IEC 14496-10, ISO/IEC 14496-15, or some other?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I is ISO 14496-10 or ITU-T h.264.